# CiviMember - end_date not updating after automatic renewal

Tags: civimember, auto-renew

I am having an issue with auto renew memberships. Civicrm 5.52.2 / Wordpress 6.0.3

The payment is going through just fine. And the statuses (after a Cron run) update just fine but the end_date does not update to reflect the renewal period. Is it a cron I'm missing ?

Please assist, and can you please let me know the name of the function/location responsible for updating the end_date so I can debug this further ?

Comment: Welcome to SE!  What payment processor are you using?

Comment: Thank you Aidan for the welcoming and for your prompt response. 

GlobalIris Payment Processor. ver 2.0

Answer (score 1):

The end date should update immediately, when the payment is processed and a contribution is created in CiviCRM. This doesn't require a cron job.

I suggest you check to see that the contributions are correctly linked to the membership (via the membership payment table). If you view the membership it should show the related contributions and recurring contributions. If they aren't linked correctly this will mean that the membership doesn't update when a new payment is received.

Comment: Hello William, thank you for your time in looking into this. As you said I narrowed down the issue to the civicrm_membership_payment table which doesn't get updated when the payment is received. There is no entry of the latest contribution found in the civicrm_contribution table.

Comment: One more thing I wanted to add. Once we added the relationship manually on the civicrm_membership_payment for the missing recurrences and re-run the corn to update the status of the membership the end date again didn't update.

Comment: If a membership payment isn't created when the payment is received that sounds like an issue with the payment processor. I'm not familiar with that payment processor. It may be that it doesn't support recurring payments.

If this is the payment processor you are using it says it only supports one off payments. https://civicrm.org/extensions/global-payments

Comment: I'm afraid running the cron won't help with this. The end date should be updated when the payment is received.

Comment: Again William thank you for your time and effort. I believe it is a  bespoke extension that they built on top of that one. The only weird bit about it is when we renew the subscription in any other way, meaning from the clients' account, email with renewal link etc it works, it's just the autorenewal that fails to update the expected new membership end date.

Comment: William thank you for all your help, I switched the payment gateway to Stripe and everything works now like a charm!

Comment: Great! Glad to hear it's working for you now.